# Is this a valid method for seeing if 2 cookies are set using php within javascript

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

Lets pretend we have a JavaScript function named `is_set()` which has two php calls and are used to find a boolean parameter for an `if` statement like so.

```
function is_set()
{
    if((true == <?php if( isset($_COOKIE["set_1"]))?>) && (true == <?php if( isset($_COOKIE["set_2"]))?>))
        return true;
    else
        return false;       

}
```

Is it valid to do this or am I supposed to use an `echo` somewhere within  ?

Here's the complete [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746041/setting-a-cookie-with-php-within-js-gives-me-an-error-on-line-29-returning-a-va/21746056#21746056). I started this thread because it was a different topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reduce it to:

```
function is_set(){
    return <?php echo(isset($_COOKIE["set_1"]) && isset($_COOKIE["set_2"]));?>;
}
```